# ModuleError: no module named 'darkdetect'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I have downloaded a module called customtkinter. This module itself required me to download darkdetect, so I have downloaded both. Please see this below.

[image]

However, when I run the following code, I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
```

[image]

I have tried reinstalling both customtkinter and darkdetect, however I get the same issue. Here is also a picture of my directories (I downloaded the customtkinter source code from [this github](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/tree/master/customtkinter) and saved it in my project folder)

[image]

Comment: Have you just named your file as `customtkinter.py`?

Comment: No I have named the file "Adaptation X V1.py"

Comment: another file in that same directory that is named like this?

Comment: Please post the full error traceback not as picture, but as text.

Comment: I will add a screenshot of the directory

Comment: No just add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Added the directories and the full traceback error

Comment: I'll guess it works when you rename the folder, doesn't it?

Comment: I renamed the folder to "test" and got a "ModuleNotFoundError: no module names customtkinter"

Comment: Can you import any other module in that script ? Like `import time` ?

Comment: Yes importing time and using time works. Is there a problem with the way I downloaded customtkinter? Are the files I have placed in the directory incorrect?

Comment: I checked the documentation and copied the files from here https://pypi.org/project/customtkinter/0.3/#files

Comment: I have added a large update which narrows down the problem slightly further. Please review it and let me know if you could help in any way!

Comment: So clearly you're installing modules, via `pip`, to a different Python installation than the one you're running scripts from. This is an extremely common issue that's posted about on here, so if you do a bit of searching I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: If you run `pip list` in a terminal, does `customtkinter` appear in the list shown?

Comment: If you have installed both modules via `pip`, then remove the `customtkinter` directory inside your project directory.

Comment: I tried removing the customtkinter folder from my project directory however when I run the code I get "ImportError: no module name customtkinter"

Comment: Never mind! This has worked now. I tried it on a different machine (as I am utilising university labs) and reinstalled customtkinter. It now works! Thanks for your help everyone :)